# Change the css of li and div on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is my view:

```
  <div class="tabbable">                    
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
             <li id="liTab1" class="active"><a id="a1" data-toggle="tab">Upload TOT Master</a></li>
             <li id="liTab2"><a id="a2" data-toggle="tab">View TOT Master</a></li>
             <li id="liTab3"><a id="a3" data-toggle="tab">Upload TOT Master Adhoc</a></li>
          </ul>
     <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
              <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
              <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
              <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 3.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The above code which represents the view in tab container format like below:

[image]

On changing the tab, I want its corresponding content div should become active and remaining tab would become inactive. I used the below javascript function, but its not working:

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#a1").click(function () {
        $("#liTab1").addClass('active');
        $("#liTab2").removeClass('active');
        $("#liTab3").removeClass('active');
        $("#tab1").addClass('tab-pane active');
        $("#tab2").addClass('tab-pane inactive');
        $("#tab3").addClass('tab-pane inactive');
    });

    $("#a2").click(function () {
        $("#liTab1").removeClass('active');
        $("#liTab2").addClass('active');
        $("#liTab3").removeClass('active');
        $("#tab2").addClass('tab-pane active');
        $("#tab1").addClass('tab-pane inactive');
        $("#tab3").addClass('tab-pane inactive');
    });

    $("#a3").click(function () {
        $("#liTab1").removeClass('active');
        $("#liTab2").removeClass('active');
        $("#liTab3").addClass('active');
        $("#tab3").addClass('tab-pane active');
        $("#tab1").addClass('tab-pane inactive');
        $("#tab2").addClass('tab-pane inactive');
    });

});
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please create fiddle and post link here?

Comment: You are using `twitter-bootstrap`?

Comment: Why would you re-add the class `tab-pane`, it's already there, you don't have to add it again.

Comment: Yes.. I am using this template for my design "http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB042R743/index.html"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Twitter-bootstrap-tabs` have one more property in `html` called `data-target` which when set to its corresponding `tab` target will automatically do this for you without any help of `javascript`. Check the below code and **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ft16fcqL/1/)** here

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li id="liTab1" class="active"><a id="a1" data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Upload TOT Master</a></li>
     <li id="liTab2"><a id="a2" data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">View TOT Master</a></li>
     <li id="liTab3"><a id="a3" data-target="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Upload TOT Master Adhoc</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to access the item individually nor you have to add the anchor inside the list. You can just change the pointer using css.

You can change html in this way:

```
<li id="liTab1" class="active" data-tab="tab1">Upload TOT Master</li>
<li id="liTab2" data-tab="tab2">View TOT Master</li>
<li id="liTab3" data-tab="tab3">Upload TOT Master Adhoc</li>
```

and this is the js piece of code:

```
    $('ul.nav-tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('active');
    });
```